# How can I move a MySQL database to a new localhost?

Tags: mysql, database, sql

I have a localhost (XAMPP) on an old pc. I need the MySQL database on my new mac with a localhost (MAMP). Issue is, pc doesn't have internet connection. Any way I can move the database over? Detailed instructions are highly welcomed as I am by no means a server expert. Thanks

Comment: Use a USB stick?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just use a USB Stick as suggested in the comments above.  Just make sure to remove/modify the permissions on the DB file(s) first to avoid having issues with not being able to access the DB once it is moved over.  That is a painful, painful, painful lesson if something goes wrong... experience talking.

- [Backup MySQL](http://www.instructables.com/id/Backing-up-your-SQL-database-using-XAMPP-and-phpMy/)
- Consequently, use the import link on the new PC

Comment: I assumed XAMP = Windows MAMP = Mac

Comment: I've not seen it referred to as MAMP =D  As a SQA tester I've used it on both Mac and Windows so was just wanting to clarify and was pretty sure that apache friends just called it XAMP for each os(win/mac/linux)

Answer (score 1):

XAMP should have phpmyadmin installed. If so, I would use it to create a backup / dump of the data base. Put that on your usb, move it to the mac, and again use phpmyadmin to first create a data base, then import your data.

You could also use mysqldump (at least on Linux from command line. Not sure about XAMP on windows):

mysqldump -u username -p database | gzip > database.sql.gz  ( the pipe gzip is optional)

so say your db name is db_important and your db username is phil

mysqldump -u phil -p db_important | gzip > db_important.sql.gz

( when you run this you will be asked for your db password)

Or wihout gzip:

mysqldump -u phil -p db_important > db_important.sql

phpmyadmin should be easiest and safest route for you if your unfamiliar with mysql command line

these links may help:

[back up with php admin](http://www.instructables.com/id/Backing-up-your-SQL-database-using-XAMPP-and-phpMy/?ALLSTEPS)

[how to use phpmyadmin to back up and restore](http://learn.apprendre-joomla.com/import-and-export-database-mysql-phpmyadmin.html)